# Stored procedure in master slave replication

Tags: replication, mariadb, master-slave-replication

I have a master-slave replication for a schema **products** which is being replicated with `binlog_do_db = products`.

one of the the tables in the master schema is being archived by calling a stored procedure which is in schema **products_archive**.The data is moved to a different schema on the same database from **products** to **products_archive**.

```
START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO products_archive.dial
        SELECT * FROM products.dial
        WHERE products.dial.dial_datestamp <= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
        DELETE FROM products.dial
        WHERE producst.dial.dial_datestamp <= DATE(NOw() - INTERVAL 30 DAY);
COMMIT;
```

But the slave has only one schema **products** which is not being archived.
Since stored procedure is on the schema which is not being replicated the master should be archived and the slave shouldn't.

But what instead happened is the master archive was successful and the same data got deleted on the slave.

How did the data get purged on the slave as the schema **products_archive** is not added to list of replicated schemas.

Comment: Back up a step and state what you want.  `product_archive` lives only on Master?  All rows exist in one table or the other on both?  Or do you intend to remove 'old' rows from one of the servers?

Comment: product_archive schema is on master only.All the rows exist on both master and slave table but i want to archive only master table and not slave.The stored procedure is put in the non-replicated schema products_archive to avoid archiving happening on slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what is happening is that your stored procedure deletes rows from `products.dial`, and these `DELETE` statements are simply replicated to the slave. It doesn't matter that the stored procedure itself is in a non-replicated schema.

Comment: Is this how its supposed to work?Is there a way to avoid the delete happening on the slave?

Comment: Yep, this is how replication works. It's possible to avoid the DELETE statements taking effect on the slave, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388907/mysql-replication-without-delete-statments

Comment: You are walking into a mine field.

Comment: Agreed, this is a minefield! I suppose the main thing to avoid is reusing deleted primary key values.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given code and scenario I would assume you are talking about Transactional Replication and that the command "DELETE FROM products.dial" that took place at the publisher was replicated to the subscriber. If this is the case it means that the table products.dial is defined as an article in your publication and one option that may or may not be applicable in your case is to define this specific article NOT to replicate DELETE commands. This can be done using the stored procedure [sp_changearticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changearticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

In case this is not a desired/ applicable behaviour for your case then another option can be to direct the data to be deleted at a destination table located at another database (i.e ArchiveDatabase).

Regardless of the specific issue you are raising please be aware of the syntax that can delete and direct the output to a destination table in 1 automatic command avoiding the need for an explicit transaction and that is by using the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause